# TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function- A pesar que bootstrap.js esta cargado-Angular 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Angular que tienen estos archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi `index.html` tengo las librerias css y js:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pedidos WEB GT</title>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- <base href="/P3W/"> -->


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/sweetalert2.min.css'/>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/style.css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/fontsIcon.css'/> 
  <script src="assets/js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9pnDdHXxMf0sI1sBQs-pLSvT5r2uAu7c&libraries=places&language=fr" async defer></script>
</head>
```

Voy a nombrar 2 componentes que tengo de ejemplo, `newPassword.component` y `Pedidos-Control.component`, cuando la pagina carga en el primer componente (cliente), me debe este llamo a desplegar un modal donde previamente evaluo (en `newPassword`) si el usuario debe cambiar la contraseña o no:

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.setNewPasswordForm = new FormGroup({
            newPassword: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            newPasswordConfirmation: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
        });

        let cambioClave = this.authService.getLoggedUser().cambioClave;
        console.log('cambio clave', cambioClave);

        //el usuario tiene la posibilidad de cambiar de contraseña
        if (cambioClave){        
            console.log('inside if')    
            $('#setNewPasswordModal').modal('show');
        }
    }
```

Cuando carga la pagina me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leyendo por internet veo que se debe al orden en el que las librerías están acomodadas y que `jquery.js` debi ir antes de `bootstrap.js`.

Lo extraño es que la librerías están en orden que deberían:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el componente `pedido-control` tengo un botón que al hacer click muestra un modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis dudas, si el orden de "esta malo" este modal no se deberia mostrar entonces?

El modal de `pedidos-control` se llama mediante `data-target`:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success verDetallePedido modalUsuarios" data-id={{item.IdPedido}} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-verDetalle" (click)="showDetalle(item.IdPedido)">Ver Detalle</button>
```

Mientras que `newPassword` es con `modal(show)`, cual es realmente el problema?

Comment: ¿Intentaste colocar los scripts de jquery y bootstrap (en ese orden) _al final del `body`_?

Comment: No uses Jquery con Angular, puede ocasionarte muchos problemas. En su lugar usa Angular Material, puedes usar el SASS de Bootstrap. `import * as $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: @Legna esta información es incorrecta. Ambos scripts contienes las mismas funciones. Tal vez te refieres a `jquery.slim.js`, la cual si es reducida.

Comment: @JheymanMejia Para no causar confusión, elimino mi comentario. Gracias por apuntarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que tener bootsrap y jquery en tu proyecto luego en tu componente en la parte superior de importaciones agrega para incluir jquery y poder usarlo en todo el componente:

```
declare var $:any;
```